# stack-Overflow error while removing nodes of a tree

Tags: java, swt, treeviewer

I have a tree structure in this format:

```
Index1
|
 --Key1
 --Value1 
Index2
|
 --Key2
 --Value2
```

`Key` and `Value` objects are children of `Index` objects and there are no index objects in the tree.

I'm maintaining array lists for `Index` objects (`indexList`), `Key` objects (`keyList`) and `Value` objects (`valueList`).

`viewer` is an object of `TreeViewer`.

My aim is to remove Index object and the code responsible for this action is:

```
String indexName = text.getText();

for(int i =0; i< model.indexList.size(); i++)
{                   
    if(model.indexList.get(i).getName().equals(indexName))
    {
        Index temp = model.indexList.get(i);
        int noOfKeys   =  temp.keyList.size();
        int noOfValues =  temp.valueList.size();

        for(int j=0; j<noOfKeys ; j++ )
        {
            temp.keyList.remove(j);
            temp.valueList.remove(j);
        } 

        model.indexList.remove(i);
        break;
    }
}
viewer.refresh();
```

When I perform the remove action the node gets removed but with stack-overflow error.

Please let me know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are removing items from a list in a for loop i.e.

```
for(int j=0; j<noOfKeys ; j++ )
                    {
                        temp.keyList.remove(j);
                        temp.valueList.remove(j);
                    }
```

is most probably the source for the error.

Everytime you remove something from a list the relative index values of all items will change.
For example temp.keylist.remove(0) would remove zeroth item and the item at index 1 would move to index zero. Now for the next iteration j has already incremented to 1(but instead it should have been zero)

Try commenting above section of code which I have indicated and you should not get the overflow error(This would your first check to zero in on which part of the code causes the issue)

The next step would be to try something like

```
temp.keyList.clear()
temp.valueList.clear()
```

instead of the for loop above.

Comment: I agree with yours views on this and i have modified the code accordingly , but still i face up with the same stack overflow error.

Comment: My getChildren() method of class that implements ITreeContentProvider looks like this :

   

    public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement)
  { 
   if(parentElement instanceof Index )
   {
    Index ind1 = (Index)parentElement;
    return ind1.getSetOfKeyValue();
   }
  return model.getSetOfChilds();
  }

Comment: Stacktrace

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.callWindowProc(Tree.java:1536)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4251)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5844)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4873)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessage(OS.java:3156)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.getItems(Tree.java:3249)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getChildren(TreeViewer.java:171)